# Numpy - Late Binding Closures

Tags: numpy, list-comprehension, late-binding

I guess it could be a `late binding closures` problem.

```
for i,dt in enumerate(delay_list):
    accel[:,i],freq[:,i] = srs(sum)
```

What I actually get: 2 arrays (shape: 124,3) with all 3 columns identical (corresponding to i=2)
What I expect: 2 arrays (shape: 124,3) with each column corresponding to i=0,1,2

Additional info:

`srs(sum)` is a function that loads a `txt file` (sum) with a filename that changes in accordance with the `dt` index.

This is my first post. I apologize in case of wrong formatting.

Comment: Please dummy input data (delay_list), what is its shape? Also, what is the output of srs(sum), please provide reproducable data

Comment: delay_list=np.round(list(np.arange(0.01,0.04,0.01)),2)

Comment: srs(sum) returns two arrays one column each - Thank you

Comment: What would be the shapes? Can you add the srs function as well?

Comment: You will also have to add what accel and freq are. the current details in question you have provided are insufficient for anyone to help you solve it. Do frame the problem with details and reproducable examples of each of the variables and arrays in the problem.

Comment: As written `srs(sum)` is the same each iteration.  It doesn't depend on `i` or `dt`.

Comment: yes, sum loads the txt file with the following filename:

        np.savetxt('Delay - ' + str(dt) + " .txt", (arr3))
        sum='Delay - ' + str(dt) + " .txt"

Is there a way to load the complete script?

Comment: @Akshay Sehgal
Here some more details:
"        freq=np.zeros((124,len(delay_list))) 
        accel=np.zeros((124,len(delay_list)))"
Here's an extract of the data in the file which is load by the function:
-1.000000e-001 -1.049577e+000   
-9.999023e-002 4.449292e-001   
-9.998047e-002 -1.026760e-001   
-9.997070e-002 -2.966194e-001

Comment: Hello, I finally solved just writing:

        'accel[:,i],freq[:,i] = srs('Delay - ' + str(dt) + " .txt")' 

instead of:
        'accel[:,i],freq[:,i] = srs(sum)'

I don't know why. But it works perfectly now...Thanks